# ruby on rails many to many validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have:

```
scaffold attendance event:references user:references attendance_rate:references
scaffold user name email
scaffold event start_time end_time
scaffold attendance_rate rate:integer #)[1 or 0], i do not want to use boolean)
```

Associations:

```
event has_many :attendances
attendance belongs_to :event

user has_many :attendances
attendance belongs_to :user
```

Problem: How can I permit one same user to "attend" the same event only once?

Attendance.rb:

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :attendance_rate
  belongs_to :event
  validates :user_id, :attendance_rate_id, presence: true
  validates_uniqueness_of :event_id, :scope => [:user_id]
end
```

Note: attendances are created in nested forms for events.

Comment: Unique index? `validates_uniqueness_of`?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `uniqueness` validation with `scope` option. It would be something like,

`validates_uniqueness_of :event_id, :scope => [:user_id]` in the `Attendance` model.

Comment: I added this validation to Attendance.rb, but it does not solve the issue - I can still create multiple attendances to same event with same user. Did I miss something?

Comment: @makerbreaker - How did you add? Can you show me model code?

Comment: I've edited the question. So when I create it shows no validation error, but when I edit the `attendance_rate_id` - only than it show the error for `guest_id`...